# Set Path in Windows failed

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

I am trying to set a path of in windows 7 64bit.

1st I want to install python program that works on Unix.
this is the [program](https://github.com/yumorishita/LiCSBAS/wiki/2_0_workflow#quick-start)

the problem is when I am in the step of setting the path I couldn't add it.

the command in unix in .sh file is:

```
## Path
export LICSBAS_PATH="$(cd $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}); pwd)"
export PATH="$LICSBAS_PATH/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH="$LICSBAS_PATH/LiCSBAS_lib:$PYTHONPATH"
```

when I run the test file
it give me this

```
> Check LiCSBAS commands   ERROR: PATH is not set to LiCSBAS commands

> Check LiCSBAS library   ERROR: PYTHONPATH is not set to LiCSBAS library
```

after I treied to set Environment Variables as usual
My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced > Environment Variables
and I added

```
;my_path/LiCSBAS/LiCSBAS_lib;my_path/LiCSBAS/bin
```

and nothing working, and in my test file LiCSBAS_check_install.py
I added this link at the starting

```
import sys
sys.path.append("my_path/LiCSBAS/LiCSBAS_lib")
sys.path.append("my_path/LiCSBAS/bin")
```

here, the secend message of library is solved but the PATH of bin doesn't work!!

```
Check LiCSBAS commands
ERROR: PATH is not set to LiCSBAS commands
```

any suggestions please to solve it?

Comment: Two suggestions, running command prompt as admin and rebooting your machine?